# How to enable tls1.3 in nginx?

Tags: nginx, redhat, tls1.3

I am setting up nginx in the below configured server

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.6 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.6"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.6:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.6
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.6"
```

I have installed nginx version: nginx/1.15.11 in server.
And config file looks as below

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name hub.sigmabh.io;
    return 301 https://***.***.io$request_uri;
}

server {
   listen 443 ssl;
   ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/***.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/***.pem;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
   ssl_ciphers TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AESGCM:EECDH+AES;
   server_name ***.***.io;
   server_tokens off;
   client_max_body_size 3M;

location /static/ {
   alias /home/***/static/;
}
location /static/admin {
   alias /home/***/admin/;
}


location / {
    proxy_pass https://*.*.*.*:4000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

}

I have enabled tls1.3 in goole chrome and if i make a request from browser, the application is not loading.
I am getting "There was a problem with the handshake. The site may not support a protocol or cipher we can use.", if i scan url.

TLS1.2 is working fine.
Openssl version is OpenSSL 1.0.2o  27 Mar 2018.

How to enable the tls1.3 in nginx to application?

Comment: [The manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_protocols) says you need OpenSSL 1.1.1 for TLSv1.3

Comment: How to install nginx with openssl 1.1.1b?
I have installed openssl 1.1.1b but still nginx is taking openssl 1:1.0.2k-16.el7_6.1.
I need to install nginx with openssl 1.1.1b